# How to INSERT INTO a table that contains a non identity field primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attempting to INSERT INTO a table in a commercial database where I cannot change the schema. The insert is attempting to load hundreds of records. The table I am inserting into contains a primary key field that is not an Identify field. What is the best method for completing these inserts while maintaining the integrity of the primary key field?

```
INSERT INTO ADVANCED.BIF006 ( C_CUSTOMER, C_ACCOUNT, C_ADDTYPE, I_BIF006PK)
VALUES (
  '', -- C_CUSTOMER - char(15)
  '', -- C_ACCOUNT - char(15)
  '', -- C_ADDTYPE - char(2)
  ???, -- I_BIF006PK - decimal(15, 0)
)
```

Comment: Just insert all the rows, including the PK values. I feel there's something you are not saying. What's the database engine? How does an `INSERT` statement look? Does the table already have data in it? Do you have duplicate keys?

Comment: You don't have to maintain the integrity of the PK field, the database does that for you, the question is do you already have PK values or do you need to generate them?

Comment: The SQL Server table does have data in it. The application increments the field itself opposed to auto incrementing through an Identity field. Below is the generalized Insert statement. What I am trying to do is figure out how to do this bulk insert while inserting the correct value for I_BIF006PK. Basically I need to check the table for the MAX value of this field and add one to it for each of the records.

Comment: INSERT INTO ADVANCED.BIF006
(
    C_CUSTOMER,
    C_ACCOUNT,
    C_ADDTYPE,
    I_BIF006PK

VALUES
(   '',        -- C_CUSTOMER - char(15)
    '',        -- C_ACCOUNT - char(15)
    '',        -- C_ADDTYPE - char(2)
   ???,      -- I_BIF006PK - decimal(15, 0)
    )

Comment: Can't you just use a `SEQUENCE` to provide new values for the PK? Set its starting value to the max existing value + 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a guess since I don't have all the details. I hope it helps.

Let's assume the current existing table before the data load has a PK with a maximum value of `1000`. Then, the new rows could start at `1001`. To do this you could use a sequence. For example:

```
create sequence load_seq1 start with 1001

INSERT INTO ADVANCED.BIF006 ( C_CUSTOMER, C_ACCOUNT, C_ADDTYPE, I_BIF006PK)
VALUES (
  '', -- C_CUSTOMER - char(15)
  '', -- C_ACCOUNT - char(15)
  '', -- C_ADDTYPE - char(2)
  next value for load_seq1, -- I_BIF006PK - decimal(15, 0)
)

drop sequence load_seq1
```

Comment: I was not previously familiar with using a sequence. I looked this up real quick and it appears to be exactly what I am looking for. Thank you very much!!!!